# Find float number in string with php

Tags: php, regex, string, floating-point

I have these strings:

```
$txt1 = "8,742 MW";
$txt2 = "7,750 KW";
$txt2 = "2,350 GW";
```

I need a regex to find the valid float number into these strings... How can I do it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match float value try following regexp:

```
(\d+(?:,\d+)?)
```

Also you can just cast it to a float using:

```
$floatVal = (float) "8,742 MW";
```

Comment: `if (preg_match("(\d+(?:,\d+)?)", $txt1, $matches)) {
        $value = $matches[0];
        print "value=$value\n";
    }`

Comment: $floatVal = (float) "8,742 MW"; // It will work if you replace the ',' by '.'

Answer (score 1):

This one should do it :

```
[-+]?([0-9]*\,)?[0-9]+
```

Or if you'd like to convert directly to a float by taking the comma "," as a dot ".", then I think you should set your locale to a french one as stated [here](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/language.types.float.php#92885) :

```
setLocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_BE.UTF-8');
```